# XPath: first child, but only if specific tag

Tags: xpath

I need an XPath expression that finds a node with a specific number, type, and order of children. E.g. we need an `expr` with three children of types `expr`, `LEFT_ASSIGN` and `expr`, in this order:

```
//expr[count(child::*)=3]
  [*[1][name()='expr']
  [*[2][name()='LEFT_ASSIGN']
  [*[3][name()='expr']
```

This works, but it is quite cumbersome to write, especially because often I need to embed similar conditions into each other. E.g. I need to specify that the first `expr` child above also has a specific set of children, etc:

```
//expr[count(child::*)=3]
  [*[1][name()='expr'][count(child::*)=1][SYMBOL[count(child::*)=0]]]
  [*[2][name()='LEFT_ASSIGN']]
  [*[3][name()='expr']]
```

Is there a shorter, simpler way?

Here is some sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"standalone="yes" ?>
<exprlist>
  <expr>
    <expr>
      <SYMBOL>X</SYMBOL>
    </expr>
    <LEFT_ASSIGN>&lt;-</LEFT_ASSIGN>
    <expr>
      <expr>
        <NUM_CONST>42</NUM_CONST>
      </expr>
      <OP-STAR>*</OP-STAR>
      <expr>
        <NUM_CONST>42</NUM_CONST>
      </expr>
    </expr>
  </expr>
  <OP-SEMICOLON>;</OP-SEMICOLON>
  <expr>
    <expr>
      <SYMBOL>Y</SYMBOL>
    </expr>
    <LEFT_ASSIGN>&lt;-</LEFT_ASSIGN>
    <expr>
      <NUM_CONST>42</NUM_CONST>
    </expr>
  </expr>
</exprlist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way in XPath to write `*[1][name()='expr']` is `*[1][self::expr]`.

`//expr[count(child::*)=3]` can be shortened to `//expr[count(*)=3]`.

`SYMBOL[count(child::*)=0]` is usually written as `SYMBOL[not(*)]`.

Comment: Thanks, these are helpful! Btw. I suppose there is no way to simply tell XPath to do just consider the order of the child nodes as they are specified, and one needs to write `*[1][self::expr]`.